# Python Tornado: Fetching values from database tables

Tags: python, tornado, psql

I tried executing the below code. Here, it prints the correct value for **usr** as admin but not for **did**. It should be fetching the id of the corresponding username admin and giving value as DOC1, from the doctors table. Instead, it prints as None. I am not able to figure out why None comes and not DOC1.

```
def post(self):
    usr = self.current_user
    did = self.db.execute("SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE username ='%s'" % usr;")
    print usr
    print did
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am getting.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have extraneous characters (;”) after the last ‘usr’ variable at the end. remove those.

Comment: I tried removing it also. But still, it seems to show the same output.

Comment: do you get any error messages? add those to your question.

Comment: I just figured out the execute function actually return none and a fetchall function needs to be used for getting the value.